# Running order of compenents and its elements with <Navigate/>

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, navigation

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { WorkoutsContextProvider } from './context/WorkoutContext'
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContext'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <WorkoutsContextProvider>
        <App />
      </WorkoutsContextProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  // </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthContext } from './hooks/useAuthContext'
import { useEffect }from 'react'

// pages & components
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Signup from './pages/Signup'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

function App() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext()
  console.log("main")

  console.log("user:  ",user)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App useffect")
        
  }, [])

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="pages">
        {console.log("Route main")}
          <Routes>
            <Route 

              path="/"
              element={user ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> } 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/login" 
              element={!user ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
            <Route 
              path="/signup" 
              element={!user ? <Signup /> : <Navigate to="/" />} 
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from "react"


export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return { user: action.payload }
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return { user: null }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, { 
    user: null  
  })
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  console.log("how many times")

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('AuthContext useffect here:', state)

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

    if (user) {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: user }) 
    }

    // setEmail("ciho@gmail.com")

  }, [])

  console.log('AuthContext state:', state)
  console.log('AuthContext email:', email)

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )

}
```

Hey everyone i am trying to figure out something that confuses me, its about running order of compenents and its elements.

At the initial load of app user value is null by default, when i want to route to "/" page, app redirects us to "/login" page as normal but the problem is why navigate compenent immediately doesnt render the login page when there is match, i know navigate returns null and simply triggers its useffect something like this

```
function Navigate() {
  React.useEffect(
    () => navigate(JSON.parse(jsonPath), { replace, state, relative }),
    [navigate, jsonPath, relative, replace, state]
  );

  return null;
}
```

After that stage useffects need to get executed from child compenent to parent compenents useffect but why app doesnt render the login compenent immediately after useeffect of navigate component gets triggered and why waits for parents useeffect, what kind of thing causes that behaviour ?